# How to ensure connections to certain hosts are routed via ethernet?

Tags: mac, wifi, network

We have a mac that acts as a CI-server.

It needs to connect to our git-repositories which can only be connected to via ethernet.

All other servers, apple.com, github.com, etc. need to be connected via wifi, because our ethernet is running a MITM-scheme for all SSL-connections.

I thought about setting routes manually, routing certain IPs to specific gateways. However, the IPs themselves are changing, too.

So to connect to our git repo, at any time, I would have to do the following:

1. Turn off wireless adapter
2. Resolve ip of git server using nameserver in ethernet network
3. Turn on wireless adapter
4. Add static route

Is this correct?

Is there a better way to do it? Perhaps with some UI-tool?

Answer (score 1):

Use VLANs. Put your wifi on one VLAN, and your internal network on another VLAN. Don't allow wifi users to access the internal VLAN, and make sure hard wired connections are on the internal VLAN.

This lets your switch/router handle the job, instead of setting up individual routes on employee machines.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for answering, but think I probably described my problem badly. There's no users, it's just a stand alone computer that needs to access some networks from one interface, and other networks from another interface. I have solved the problem for now using static routes and /etc/hosts entries (b/c DNS servers can be in either network), but it doesn't work if the IPs change.

Comment: You can use VLAN's with a single computer. Same setup as described. It will survive IP changes.